# Example of a set that is Dedekind-finite but not Tarski-finite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

Can you give an example of a set that is Dedekind-finite, but *not* Tarski-finite?

Comment: How do *you* define Tarski-finite? (There are two interpretations for the term, one equivalent to "finite" in the most strict way, and another which is not.)

Comment: Start with the definition you gave earlier: $A$ is finite if and only if for every non-empty $U\subseteq\mathcal P(A)$ there exists a $\subseteq$-maximal element in $U$.

Answer (score 2):

First let me set the definitions, so there will be no fuss about the terms I use later on.

1. Finite means bijectible with a finite ordinal.
2. Dedekind-finite means "every self-injection is a bijection" (or equivalently, every self-injection is surjective).
3. Tarski-finite means that for every non-empty set of subsets has a $\subseteq$-maximal element.
4. Whenever "infinite" is being used, possibly with one of the above modifiers, the meaning is that the set does not satisfy the relevant definition of being finite (e.g. Dedekind-infinite means not Dedekind-finite).

It is provable in $\sf ZF$ that every Tarski-finite set is finite. However it is consistent with the failure of the axiom of choice that there is an infinite set which is Dedekind-finite.

But because this is a consistency result, the word "example" is misleading. Since we cannot prove, nor disprove this, from the axioms of $\sf ZF$, giving a concrete example is impossible.

In the model defined by Paul Cohen, in which the real numbers cannot be well-ordered, he does that by adding an infinite Dedekind-finite set of real numbers. Since Tarski-finiteness is the same as finiteness, this is an "example" as you are asking for. But it cannot be "given explicitly" because this is a consistency result, rather than a provability result.

---

One can weaken the definition of Tarski-finite, and require that only $U$ which is linearly ordered by $\subseteq$ will have a maximal element; and under the axiom of choice this is again equivalent to being finite (and Dedekind-finite). But there are examples, similar in nature, but different from, the example I gave due to Cohen, that this weakened definition is not equivalent to being finite, or being Dedekind-finite.

Comment: Thanks, but a set that cannot be "given explicitly" (as you might expect for "an infinite Dedekind-finite set") is not very satisfying. Can its existence be proven in ZF or ZFC?

Comment: It can be proved that Dedekind-finite and Tarski-finite are equivalent in $\sf ZFC$. In $\sf ZF$ you cannot disprove that, because that would imply that you can prove the negation of the axiom of choice (which we know is impossible). Therefore the only thing you are left with is a consistency result: it is possible that the definitions define different objects.

Comment: A good argument in favour of AC, is it not? Without it, you get this seemingly paradoxical result.

Comment: You get plenty of paradoxical results with, and plenty of paradoxical results without.